# Raspberry LIN shield

Tags: pi-3, lin-bus

Im a beginner with Raspberry Pi and I want to connect a LIN Bus shield to it. I searched on the internet everywhere but I still can´t find a LIN shield for  the RPi. is that normal? can you please help me with that ? is it possible to make my own LIN shield ?
Waiting for your answers which will certainly help me with my project.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get LIN working in Linux is to implement a custom UART driver (or, more precisely, a TTY discipline), and use a level converter to make the UART work with 12V.

On the software side, take a look at [slLIN](https://github.com/trainman419/linux-lin/tree/master/sllin) project. Its authors also wrote a [paper](https://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/can/sllin-rtlws14-paper.pdf) about it, which may help to understand how it works.

On the hardware side, buy a UART or an RS-232 module and make a 12V level converter for it. Example from the paper above:

[image]